# Installing the QGIS C++ API for Visual Studio?

Tags: qgis, installation, api, c++

I've recently being trying to get the C++ API working in Visual Studio, but there really not allot of information out there.

I've found these code examples https://github.com/ranchodeluxe/qgis_cpp_plugin_cookbook

But I just don't know how to install the API for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the QGIS API working for Windows. There are to way to have it to work.

First, you can build the binaries from the source. Second way, you can download the binaries from OSGeo server. Look that : [How To: Installation and Setup of QGIS with OSGeo4W](https://github.com/APIS-Luftbildarchiv/APIS/wiki/How-To:-Installation-and-Setup-of-QGIS-with-OSGeo4W-(to-use-the-APIS-QGIS-Plugin)).